# Blow someone off

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

The babysitter blew me off at the last minute, so I had to change my plans.

Is "blew me off" a very natural expression to use like this? Will it be understood by all native speakers? Are there other and more natural things to say instead?

Comment: Yes it's a very common saying, at least in the US. You could also say "she stood me up" which has a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ***to blow someone off*** is an English phrase. It means to fail to keep an appointment with someone. Check [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03i1Vx6P2FoJZm2dwXXwpOIVC-5QQ%3A1607894415225&source=hp&ei=j4XWX-eYC4voUdGjmbgE&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX9aTn_W8f4n97tnzlq-2ZgMszslZDSvW&q=blow%20someone%20off%20phrase%20meaning&oq=blow%20someone%20o&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgCMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoICAAQyQMQkQI6CwgAELEDEIMBEJECOggIABCxAxCDAToOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6BwguECcQkwI6CAguEMkDEJECOgUILhCRAjoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6BwguELEDEEM6BQgAELEDOgoIABCxAxDJAxBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgQILhBDOgIILjoFCC4QsQM6CAguELEDEJMCOgUIABDJAzoICC4QxwEQrwFQkBFY-idgmEZoAXAAeACAAe8DiAHMH5IBCTAuNS40LjAuNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQo&sclient=psy-ab) for a definition and [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk010QjveDUSwDzyHeupSgXQflMhVYg%3A1607894425188&ei=mYXWX4-IC8iO1fAPksSQsAk&q=blow%20someone%20off%20synonym&oq=blow%20someone%20off%20phrase%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMhEIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDlAhCLAzIRCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ5QIQiwMyEQgAELADEIoDELcDEOUCEIsDMhEIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDlAhCLAzIRCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ5QIQiwMyEQgAELADEIoDELcDEOUCEIsDMhEIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDlAhCLAzIRCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ5QIQiwMyEQgAELADEIoDELcDEOUCEIsDMhEIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDlAhCLA1AAWABg2BRoAXAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKuAEBwAEB&sclient=psy-ab) for some synonyms. It is rather colloquial.

Comment: ... an *American* English phrase....